# How to write my build parameter in file as key and value using python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build with a build parameter "WorkspaceName" and I have a python script which prints the WorkspaceName and it has to write the workspace name into a file like WorkspaceName="The value provided in Jenkins build".

```
 import time
 import os
 wsname = os.getenv("WorkspaceName")
 print (wsname)
 fo = open("MyParameters.properties", "w+")
 fo.write(wsname)
 fo.close()
```

If I use dictionary, it prints in file like this `{1: 'aaa'}`

But I need as key=value, (WorkspaceName=MyWorkspaceName). I am new to python.

Comment: Is `wsname` already a dictionary? Or are you getting `json` content from the environment?

Comment: wsname is a build parameter from Jenkins build.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `dict` is implemented to print by default. If you want it differently, you'll have to pull out the parts you want and format accordingly. You can iterate both keys and values by using the `dict.items()` method:

```py
with open('MyParameters.properties', 'w+') as fo:
    for key, val in wsname.items():
        new_line = f'{key}="{val}"'
        # Or using format -> '{0}="{1}"'.format(key, val)

        # Writes to open file, adds a newline at the end
        print(new_line, file=fo)
```

Comment: Could not get the code mentioned. Can you pls explain a bit clear on the iteration part ?

Comment: The [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method returns a collection of 2-tuples (`(key, value)`). You can do what I did above to use Python's value unpacking to automatically assign the portions of the tuple to 2 distinct variables. It would effectively be the same as doing: `for item in wsname.items():...key = items[0]...val = items[1]`